# If $f(X)$ is compact Hausdorff and $f$ is a continuous map, then is $X$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ and be topological spaces and suppose $Y$ is compact Hausdorff. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function.

If $f(X)$ is compact Hausdorff, then is $X$ compact Hausdorff?

Comment: Does $t\mapsto \exp({it})$ work?

Comment: Perhaps more snappily: let $Y = \{y\}$ be a single point, and let $f:X \to Y$ be the function $x \mapsto y$ for all $x$.  Then, $f$ is continuous and $Y$ is compact Hausdorff, but $X$ could be **anything**.

Comment: What is the image of $[0,2\pi)$ under the  continuous function $f(x)=\sin x$?

Comment: These would all be great answers. Maybe someone should post one.

Comment: Yet another example: $f(x)=\sin(x)$, the image is the closed interval.

Comment: No.  Singletons are always compact sets.  Pick your favorite non compact space $X$.  Map everything to a point in $Y$ under $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X:=\mathbb{R}$, $Y:=\{0\}$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the (standard) Euclidean topology and $f:X\to Y, f(x)=0$. Then clearly $Y$ is compact and Hausdorff, but $X$ is not compact.